# Jquery Autocomplete Sample - Unnecessary Code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

While surfing Stackoverflow for an autocomplete issue to be solved, I found the perfect solution i was looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/48/

The only problem is...

```
$('a.ui-input-clear').click(function() {
    $("input[data-type='search']").val('');
    $("input[data-type='search']").trigger('keyup');
});
```

I have no idea why this part exists :S  .... clearly < a > tags don't have 'ui-input-clear' with them. That means this jquery code won't work... Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you found the answer on StackOverflow, then why don't you ask the person who provided the solution?

Comment: There clearly is an anchor tag with said class in the jsfiddle you provided

Comment: I thought posting it here might help others who have the same question as I do. Thank you for both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an onload or `$(document).ready()` function which call the `autocomplete`, right?

In fact, it's the `autocomplete` object on the jQuery library wich would add this class `ui-input-clear` to the link where the autocomplete was attached.
See the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) doc to understand.

Comment: Both Juhana and you gave me a good answer... but you explained me why this was happening with a helpful doc link.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the browser's dev tools to look at the generated DOM, you'll see this element:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text" data-theme="c">...
```

That's what the click event targets. It's added by the jQuery Mobile library.

Comment: Thank you. I've never imagined that there could be more than what i see from the codes.  Thanks :)